# DirectX 9 app slows down when camera is very close to my 260k poly mesh

Tags: c++, camera, directx, mesh, directx-9

I have built a OBJMesh loader in DirectX 9 and I was testing it. Everything seems to be working fine, expect that when I move my camera very close to my 260,000 poly model, the application slows down. But when I move the camera away, the application seems to be running fine. Does anyone know whats the problem with this?

Comment: There is only one who knows: profiler! Well, maybe GPU profiler is a second one =)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like you're spending too much time in your pixel shader.

When you get close to your model, lots of the screen is occupied by your model, therefore the pixel shader that you have associated with the model will be called frequently.

Do you have a particularly advanced pixel shader loaded?

Try commenting out your pixel shader loading or try switching it for a much simpler pixel shader, and see if that improves the frame rate.

The other option would be to switch to wireframe mode using:

```
pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_FILLMODE, D3DFILL_WIREFRAME);
```

This means that your pixel shader is only called for the edges of your vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any sort of collision detection, frustrum culling and the like. You might be passing a bounding box test when at a certain distance but as you get closer the collision detection uses more accurate methods maybe even per vertex?

As others have mentioned a profiler should help you out here.